# Several Read-Only DB Connections in Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

We have a Spring+Hibernate application (using Spring 2, from AppFuse 1.9) which is in a desperate need to be updated to Spring 3.  We're slowly working on that.

In the meantime, I'd like to take some of the load off our primary database server, and set up the read-only controllers (which just display information) to read from our database slaves.

More specifically, we have multiple databases servers (master+slaves), and I'd like to be able to set up multiple database connections, and then specify that controller1 uses db1, and controller's 2 and 3 use db2.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that with `AbstractRoutingDataSource` class in Spring. This [blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) should help you. You can wire each data source for each of your controllers.

Comment: I was pretty hopeful ... but we are using the L2 cache in Hibernate, but based on the comments in that blog, going this route would somehow cause a problem for the L2 cache?

Comment: We also use L2 cache, but we have all the primary keys as globally generated UUIDs.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'm wrong, but considering that the L2 cache will only be revoked / evicted from a change in the primary database (only one database), because the other databases would be read-only, this should be fine?

Comment: I think so, but then I am not the expert here :( - What I can tell is we have it working pretty well with the UUIDs as primary keys